# Compare three (or more) dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I have three dataframes that I want to compare with dplyr.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  name = c("Smith", "Winter", "Summer"),
  zip = c(12345, 23456, 34567),
  value = c(1, 2, 3)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 5),
  name = c("Smith", "Winter", "Summer", "Taylor"),
  zip = c(12345, 23456, 34567, 56789),
  value = c(4, 5, 6, 0)
)

df3 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 4),
  name = c("Smith", "Winter", "Miller"),
  zip = c(12345, 23456, 45678),
  value = c(7, 8, 9)
)
```

The dataframes have columns with similar values (i.e. `id`, `name`, `zip`) and a column with a random number (`value`).

What I would like to achieve is a dataframe that shows which rows of the columns with the similar values (`id`, `name`, `zip`) are present in which dataframes (I am aware that I can remove the `value` column with `select`, I just wanted to leave it in to show that the dataset also contains variable elements).

I am looking for something like this in the end.

| id | name | zip | present_in_df1 | present_in_df2 | present_in_df3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Smith | 12345 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 2 | Winter | 23456 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 3 | Summer | 34567 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4 | Miller | 45678 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 5 | Taylor | 56789 | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |

Of course, I also open for other solutions, if there is a better way of doing that instead of this representation in the end.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the three dfs together, `group_by` the relevant columns, then use `summarise` to output what df contains the necessary information.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, .id = "df") %>% 
  group_by(id, name, zip) %>% 
  summarize(df = paste(df, collapse = ","))

# A tibble: 5 × 4
     id name     zip df   
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 Smith  12345 1,2,3
2     2 Winter 23456 1,2,3
3     3 Summer 34567 1,2  
4     4 Miller 45678 3    
5     5 Taylor 56789 2
```

This could be your endpoint if you find the above format useful. To extract them into three different columns, we can `grepl` on the df number.

```
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, .id = "df") %>% 
  group_by(id, name, zip) %>% 
  summarize(df = paste(df, collapse = ","), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(present_in_df1 = grepl("1", df),
         present_in_df2 = grepl("2", df),
         present_in_df3 = grepl("3", df), .keep = "unused")

# A tibble: 5 × 6
     id name     zip present_in_df1 present_in_df2 present_in_df3
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <lgl>          <lgl>          <lgl>         
1     1 Smith  12345 TRUE           TRUE           TRUE          
2     2 Winter 23456 TRUE           TRUE           TRUE          
3     3 Summer 34567 TRUE           TRUE           FALSE         
4     4 Miller 45678 FALSE          FALSE          TRUE          
5     5 Taylor 56789 FALSE          TRUE           FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

You could bind your data frames by row, then use e.g. `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(tidyr)

dplyr::lst(df1, df2, df3) |> 
  bind_rows(.id = "df") |> 
  mutate(value = TRUE) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = df, values_from = value, names_prefix = "present_in_", values_fill = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>      id name     zip present_in_df1 present_in_df2 present_in_df3
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <lgl>          <lgl>          <lgl>         
#> 1     1 Smith  12345 TRUE           TRUE           TRUE          
#> 2     2 Winter 23456 TRUE           TRUE           TRUE          
#> 3     3 Summer 34567 TRUE           TRUE           FALSE         
#> 4     5 Taylor 56789 FALSE          TRUE           FALSE         
#> 5     4 Miller 45678 FALSE          FALSE          TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

With `reduce` and `joins`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
lst(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
  imap(\(x, y){colnames(x)[4] <- glue::glue("present_in_{y}"); x}) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = c("id", "name", "zip")) %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("present"), complete.cases))

  id   name   zip present_in_df1 present_in_df2 present_in_df3
1  1  Smith 12345           TRUE           TRUE           TRUE
2  2 Winter 23456           TRUE           TRUE           TRUE
3  3 Summer 34567           TRUE           TRUE          FALSE
4  5 Taylor 56789          FALSE           TRUE          FALSE
5  4 Miller 45678          FALSE          FALSE           TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
list(df1,df2,df3) |> purrr::reduce(full_join, by = c("id", "name", "zip"), ) |> 
  mutate(across(contains("value"), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), FALSE, TRUE))) |> 
  rename(present_in_df1 = value.x, 
         present_in_df2 = value.y, 
         present_in_df3 = value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Rowbind them, then reshape long-to-wide:

```
library(data.table)

l <- rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "^df")), idcol = "df")

dcast(l, id + name + zip ~ df)
#    id   name   zip  1  2  3
# 1:  1  Smith 12345  1  4  7
# 2:  2 Winter 23456  2  5  8
# 3:  3 Summer 34567  3  6 NA
# 4:  4 Miller 45678 NA NA  9
# 5:  5 Taylor 56789 NA  0 NA
```